# Selenium not able to open new Window/Tab

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am currently trying to crawl a website using selenium.
I have a table with elements and I want to click on each element, open the link in a new window/tab, process this window/tab, close it and click on the next element etc. So far I can click on the elements of the table, open the link and process the page.
Unfortunately I can not open the link in a new window or tab.

I can not send keyboard commands to the elements.
I have also tried

```
action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    action.move_to_element(ele)\
    .key_down(Keys.SHIFT)\
    .click(ele)\
    .key_up(Keys.SHIFT)\
    .perform()
```

This somehow does only open the link in the current window (I dont't get a new window handle, still just one).
I would be very grateful for any help.

Edit: Also I am not able to open the link in a new window/tab manually with the browser.

Comment: I don't see you using CTRL+T for tab opening ?

Comment: But I would have to send CTRL+T to the element right? I can't send keyboard commands to the element. I get the error: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element. I tried element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'T')

Comment: That error is because you're losing focus of the page. Use driver.WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME,'classname'))

Comment: I tried the following: id = ele.get_attribute('id') ele=WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,id)))
        ele.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'T')  I still get the cannot focus element error. ele was send as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @Prany He's trying to use SHIFT+<Click> to open the link in a new tab, not use CTRL+T. When you use CTRL+T, it opens a new tab with no URL. He would have to get the URL (if possible) and then send it to the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

To access the URL e.g. `https://www.google.co.in` then to click on an element e.g. *link with text* as **Gmail** to open the link in a new window/tab you can use `action_chains` class as per the solution below :

- Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  mail_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Gmail")))
  ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(mail_link).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot :

[image: Google_Gmail]

Comment: I found a different way to solve my Problem. Apparently it is not possibly to open my link in a new window/tab. The website is javascript generated and the link is in a dynamic javascript table. I think maybe the only way to have it open the link in a new window/tab, would be to send a javascript script.

Comment: @MiepMiep It doesn't matters even if the `link is in a dynamic javascript table` as we already have a _waiter_ there. Of-coarse you can use _ javascript_ as well. But my solution was constructed following your code trials through _ActionChains_

Answer (score 0):

As Gmail is an 'a' tag, first get that a tag like below and perform an actionchain

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
gmailtag = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('path to gmail') # you can use any other methods to get it.

#Now you can run this to open the gmailtag in a new tab
ActionChains(webdriver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(gmailtag).perform()

# this also worked for me
gmailtag.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+Keys.ENTER)
```

It would open Gmail in a new tab. It worked for me.